# How to convert a JSON Property to an Object using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I use the following to convert a JSON into an Object:

JSON:

```
{
     "color": "blue"
}
```

Code:

```
somethingDto = objectMapper.readValue(myJson, SomethingDTO.class);
```

However, let's say that the JSON comes at the following format:

```
{
    "something": {
         "color": "blue"
    }
}
```

**What code can achieve the same result?**

Edit: There may be more properties alongside "something"

Comment: The code should be able to return an object property.

Comment: It returns UnrecognizedPropertyException, because the JSON contain keys that are not present in SomethingDTO.

Comment: It's not clear how did you get this exception. The code is not available. Just add missing property to the object.

Comment: You seem to not have properly read the question. The exception happens with the code I provided, when the input is the second JSON. There are no missing property in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a root class for it for example

```
public class RootDto {
     SomethingDTO somthing;

     public SomethingDTO getSomething() {
      return somthing;
     }
    
    
     public void setSomething(SomethingDTO somthing) {
      this.somthing = somthing;
     }
}
```

Then map your JSON to it

```
RootDto rootDto = objectMapper.readValue(myJson, RootDto.class);
```

Or you can use JsonNode

```
JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(myJson);
JsonNode somethingNode = rootNode.get("something");
SomethingDTO somethingDto = objectMapper.convertValue(somethingNode, SomethingDTO.class);
```

Also, you can handle both of them in this way

```
JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(myJson);
JsonNode somethingNode = rootNode.get("something");
SomethingDTO somethingDto;
if (somethingNode != null) {
    somethingDto = objectMapper.convertValue(somethingNode, SomethingDTO.class);
} else {
    somethingDto = objectMapper.convertValue(rootNode, SomethingDTO.class);
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid this solution... I wonder if you can do it without needing to create another class.

Comment: How about JsonNode?

Comment: This is probably what I need! I will test on work tomorrow and mark your answer as correct as soon as I confirm it.

Comment: "solution ... without needing to create another class" why? It's Java -- _this is the way_

Answer (score 0):

Threre is an annotation called `@JsonRootName` which is similar to `@XmlRootElement`. That annotation indicates the name of the "root" wrapping.

```java
@JsonRootName("something")
public class SomethingDto {

    String color;

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public SomethingDto setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
        return this;
    }
}
```

After that, the fearure must be enabled:

```java
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
        .enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE)
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

Now, it will wrap / unwrap objects to desired root element(s).

```java
class WrapTest {

    private static final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
            .enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE)
            .enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

    //language=json
    private static final String input = """
            {
                "something": {
                    "color" : "blue"
                }
            }
            """;

    @Test
    void wrappedTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
        var dto = om.readValue(input, SomethingDto.class);
        Assertions.assertAll(
                () -> assertNotNull(dto),
                () -> assertEquals("blue", dto.getColor(), "color field mismatch")
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: But in this way, we can't handle both models of JSON with `something` and without it. can we?

Comment: It handles JSON with root element, but not without it. I think handle multiple type of input is a project design problem. Luckily multiple ObjectMapper can handle this. One with enabled features and the other has it disabled. Then collect exception an rethrow when both mapping was unsuccessful. Finally I just repeat it is not a developer issue. When client sometimes wraps `something`, sometimes wraps `everything`, otherwise they don't wrap `anything` is a wrong way.